# Default Configuration is Static. I have to create a web service supporting multiple clients

Tags: docusignapi

Here is my situation. I need to create a web service for our clients to use to have their clients sign documents. Each of our clients will have their own username and password, etc. with DocuSign. We are just an integration partner creating a backend integration service for them to send out signature requests. Signers won't be logging in to DocuSign to sign.

I've gotten a test working and sending a document. However, any subsequent calls fail on the second line below with an error that the key already exists. Obviously, I have to be able to change the username/password per request since we're supporting multiple client users generating signing requests. How do I get around the fact that Configuration.Default is static and causing this problem?

```
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + usr + "\", \"Password\":\"" + pwd + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
```

UPDATE:

So, I did end up switching to OAuth Code Grant authentication (see code sample below). However, this static configuration is still an issue. Each request could quite possibly have a different OAuth token associated with it. I've generated a class that I instantiate on each request that creates new ApiClient inside it. However, the default configuration is still there with the default header from the last request. This is an obvious problem. All the recipes and documentation use this configuration.default method. It seems someone must have run into this before and there must be a workaround to get the configuration set without this issue. Particularly in a service environment this could cause all kinds of problems if I did something gnarly like remove/re-readd/update that default header if it's shared among instances. I'm just not seeing the way around this.

```
CustomClass lib = new Lib();
//Inside lib this is called before creating envelopes, etc.
ApiClient dsClient = new ApiClient(userInfo.Docusign_Rooturl); // userInfo.Docusign_BaseUrl);
DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.ApiClient = dsClient;
//This is the problem bit
    DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization",<oauth_token>);
return dsClient;
```

UPDATE 2:
I believe I worked around this successfully. When initializing the ApiClient, rather than using the Default configuration object I use the following code:

```
 ApiClient dsClient = new ApiClient(<rootUrl>); 
        DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration config = new DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration(dsClient);
        config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", <oAuthToken>);
        dsClient.Configuration = config;
 EnvelopesApi api = new EnvelopesApi(dsClient.Configuration)
```

I hope that helps someone else who runs into the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authenticating users through your App you should be using the o[Auth authorization code grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html).

You can learn more about it [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html)

The **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header is for backend service integrations where there is no involvement of an end user.

---

You can  also use [Send On Behalf Of (SOBO) Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html)

> Originally designed to send envelopes on behalf of other users in an account, Send On Behalf Of (SOBO) is an authentication method that allows a user (the authenticating user) to send envelopes and to perform almost any task in the name of another user (the operating user) in the same account.

You can specify the sendOnBehalfOf value in your header

```
 <DocuSignCredentials>
     <Username>nat.irving@example.com</Username>
      <Password>S3cre+p455w0Rd</Password>
       <IntegratorKey>230546a7-9c55-40ad-8fbf-af205d5494ad</IntegratorKey>
     <SendOnBehalfOf>ruggiero.gardener@example.com</SendOnBehalfOf>
   </DocuSignCredentials>
```

Comment: This *is* a backend service integration. The username and password is that of the sender which can be different for each signing request and needs to be set in the header with each call. With the configuration using a static object that is problematic as described in the OP. No end user is getting authenticated by DocuSign, we are authenticating them.

Comment: What I need is a way to set the header with username, password and integrator key on each call if necessary which seems to be problematic in the sdk. Or an example of generating a signing request when I already have the account ID and base URL for the sender and don't need to authenticate before creating the envelope.

Comment: Hmm. My understanding was that SOBO was to send for another person in the same organization. That isn't what is happening in our use case.

Here is our workflow which DocuSign said was supported:
1) Our clients have their own DocuSign accounts.
2) They need to send documents for signing to their clients who do not have DS accounts. 
3) We are writing a web service which our applications will call. We are providing an integration.
4) We call the API passing in their user/pwd/acct Id/baseurl etc. and our integrator key to get signing uri
5) They get their custom branding from their acct

Comment: Yeah, from the link you mentioned "The platform looks up the operating user’s email or user ID to make sure that it is a member of the authenticating user’s account." That definitely won't work as they aren't on our account, they each have their own.

The problem I'm running into is simply that the SDK is automatically re-using the same header for requests because it's static. That isn't feasible for a web service. I'm just looking for a way around Configuration.*Default*.AddDefaultHeader so that each call will use it's own config values. Otherwise I guess I'll skip the SDK and call direct.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish should not be done. Your app should not have access to User's credentials. Only the user should hold their credentials and directly submit them to docusign for authentication. Thats the whole point of oAuth.

Comment: We have to have access to them at least once in order to retrieve their baseurl and accountid to store those for later, no? That is what the partner rep told us when we described our workflow.

We are only going to be an integration provider/referral account. My understanding:

OAuth won't work because then there is no integrator key.
SOBO won't work because our clients are not under a single account
Legacy is our only option. We need to get the baseurl/accountid once and store it. Once I have that how do I create an envelope for them with just that data?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm. I think where I was confused was the partner rep telling me our use case was a service integration rather than a user application. That set me down a path of using the legacy authentication. It looks like your initial post was right and we need to use the oAuth workflow using our integrator key as the client id in the initial request. Out of curiosity, what is the default expiration time for the oAuth tokens (Authorization Code Grant)?